# How to parse a JSON response for APEX REST Service

Tags: json, apex

I have written a REST class that sets a url as an endpoint to call an API. The API returns a timezone value. The url passes longitude and latitude as a parameter. The response I am getting is a complicated JSON list and I just need the Id value of the Timezone object. This is what I get as a JSON response for a lat/long value I passed:

```
{
   "Version":"2019c",
   "ReferenceUtcTimestamp":"2019-12-10T21:14:23.7869064Z",
   "TimeZones":[
      {
         "Id":"America/Los_Angeles",
         "Aliases":[
            "US/Pacific",
            "US/Pacific-New"
         ],
         "Countries":[
            {
               "Name":"United States",
               "Code":"US"
            }
         ],
         "Names":{
            "ISO6391LanguageCode":"No supported language code supplied",
            "Generic":"",
            "Standard":"",
            "Daylight":""
         },
         "ReferenceTime":{
            "Tag":"PST",
            "StandardOffset":"-08:00:00",
            "DaylightSavings":"00:00:00",
            "WallTime":"2019-12-10T13:14:23.7869064-08:00",
            "PosixTzValidYear":2019,
            "PosixTz":"PST+8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0",
            "Sunrise":"2019-12-10T07:42:22.383-08:00",
            "Sunset":"2019-12-10T16:18:49.095-08:00"
         },
         "RepresentativePoint":{
            "Latitude":34.05222222222222,
            "Longitude":-118.24277777777777
         },
         "TimeTransitions":[
            {
               "Tag":"PST",
               "StandardOffset":"-08:00:00",
               "DaylightSavings":"00:00:00",
               "UtcStart":"2019-11-03T09:00:00Z",
               "UtcEnd":"2020-03-08T10:00:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Tag":"PDT",
               "StandardOffset":"-08:00:00",
               "DaylightSavings":"01:00:00",
               "UtcStart":"2020-03-08T10:00:00Z",
               "UtcEnd":"2020-11-01T09:00:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Tag":"PST",
               "StandardOffset":"-08:00:00",
               "DaylightSavings":"00:00:00",
               "UtcStart":"2020-11-01T09:00:00Z",
               "UtcEnd":"2021-03-14T10:00:00Z"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my REST Service in APEX:

```
public class LPP_AccountTimeZone {
    public static List<String> getTimeZone(String latitude, String longitude){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();

         String url = 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?subscription-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&api-version=1.0&options=all&query='+latitude+','+longitude;

         req.SetEndPoint(url);

         req.setMethod('GET');
         HttpResponse res=http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        List<String> TimeZone = new List<String>();
        TimeZoneJSON result = TimeZoneJSON.parse(res.getBody());

        for(TimeZoneJSON.TimeZones t : result.timeZones){
            System.debug('TimeZone is' + t.Id);
            TimeZone.add(t.Id);
        }

    }

    else{
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
    }
    return TimeZone[0];
}
```

The response I got with this code (when I ran it in anonymous window) was:

> TimeZone is{Aliases=(US/Pacific, US/Pacific-New), Countries=({Code=US, Name=United States}), **Id=America/Los_Angeles**, Names={Daylight=Pacific Daylight Time, Generic=Pacific Time, ISO6391LanguageCode=en, Standard=Pacific Standard Time}, ReferenceTime={DaylightSavings=00:00:00, PosixTz=PST+8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0, PosixTzValidYear=2019, StandardOffset=-08:00:00, Sunrise=2019-12-12T07:44:13.44-08:00, Sunset=2019-12-12T16:18:47.934-08:00, Tag=PST, WallTime=2019-12-12T11:49:25.0802593-08:00}, Representativ

That is a lot of info. I just want the America/Los_Angeles part which is what Id equals (I have that bold in the response).

Another problem with this code is that it is not returning anything/is void class.
I need t return that value because a trigger is calling that method and will use this value to update a field.

Can anyone please correct my code so that it passes the correct json value and returns the value?

EDIT/UPDATE: The error I am now getting is "Variale does not exist: TimeZone (where the return statement is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JSON2APEX](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to easily generate an apex class from your JSON response. Just paste your full response in and click 'Create Apex'. This creates a class that represents your response so that you can easily retrieve fields from it *(Keep in mind this will only really work if your response is static meaning the structure and naming stay the same)*. Have a look through the class that it generates and that will give you an idea of what to do. The class has a `parse(String JSON)` method which you can call passing in your JSON response to retrieve an instance of that class with your response values. Then it's just a matter of retrieving the fields you want as you would with any object.
Here is how getting the timezone id code would look if you take this route.
(Note: *This assumes you keep the name of the class the standard 'JSON2Apex'*)

```java
if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    JSON2Apex result = JSON2Apex.parse(res.getBody()); 

    for(JSON2Apex.TimeZones t: result.timeZones){
        System.debug('TimeZone is' + t.id);
        tId.add(t);
    }
 }
```

To return a value just change `void` in the method signature to `List<String>` and return the tId list as follows `return tId;`

Comment: Hi KDH, Thank you for your help. I am still running into some problem/errors. So the response really just returns one ID(Timezone value) so it shouldnt be a List really,. It should just be on value of timezone. So I have put my new code based on your suggestion. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user3685949 Ok instead of adding the timezone to a list just simply put `return t.id;` you also could omit the for loop completely and after parsing the response just `return result.timezones[0].id;` but it's up to you what works best.

Comment: Oh you'll also need to change your methods return type from `List<String>` to just `String` since you are returning a single id @user3685949